# MS Access calls stored procedure to linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ms-access, linked-server

3 pieces to the puzzle:

1. MS Access Front end
2. SQL Server with stored procedures
3. Oracle server with data

I want to use MS Access to call a stored procedure in SQL Server, which takes data from the Oracle server to SQL Server.

Problem: when I call the stored procedure from the MS Access frontend, which is stored in SQL Server, it times out...

I can run other SQL Server stored procedures (that don't use the Oracle server) from Access, and that works without any problems (no issues with security etc.)

I can run the stored procedure in SQL Server using SSRS and it works fine (so I know the stored procedure as such works).

I use Windows authentication to access SQL Server from Access, however there is a different username and password from SQL Server to Oracle (which may be something to do with it?)

Because the stored procedure works on SQL Server, how can I get the MS Access frontend to simply run the stored procedure on SQL Server?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Have you opened SSMS as the same Windows user - the one Access is running as - to confirm the behavior?  That would really show it is a security issue with the user, which is likely and also managable.

Comment: It would also be good to know the versions of SQL Server and Access you are using.

Comment: This is hardly reproducible. How exactly are you executing the stored procedure?

Comment: you could just alter the timeout property of the query def. Or use DoEvents

Comment: Are you using an ADO connection in VBA or a pass-through query in your MS Access file to run the stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: thanks for comments.

Comment: thanks for comments.    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0  made the difference       (Thanks Doug)